# (Android) How can I put a react native view through prop in native UI component?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a listview in Android to use in react native (Native UI Component), and I want to make row-views for listview in react native and send it like

```JSX
_renderRows() {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text> TEST Letters </Text>
     </View>
  );
}


<CustomListViewAndroid
   ...
   rendorRow={this._renderRows.bind(this)} >
</CustomListViewAndroid>
```

[Here's the image...(I'm not eligible to upload picture yet..? hahah..)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2itHu.jpg)

How can I make it possible..?

Comment: Sorry mate, can you explain this a little bit further ? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @Guilherme Herzog 
Thanks for the reply, I attached a picture !

Comment: Thanks for the picture, but what is not clear is what you are trying to do, you should add more code and explain clearer. Are you trying to implement a ListView component from RN ?

Comment: @Guilherme Herzog
Sorry for unclear question... thanks for you, I'm learning how to use Stackoverflow !
Anyway, that's what I want to do.. I could say.. "Embed react-native view into react-native-ui-component" ?

Comment: Maybe the documentation on [Integration With Existing Apps](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html) might help you with this usecase.